# Whalesong not installing on OSX Lion

Tags: installation, scheme, racket

I've followed Whalesong's installation instructions, but I'm getting this error when calling the executable:

```
./whalesong
...smaia/Library/Racket/planet/300/5.3.5/cache/dyoo/whalesong.plt/1/19/parser/parse-bytecode-5.3.rkt:372:20: match: wrong number for fields for structure mod: expected 16 but got 15
  at: (name srcname self-modidx prefix provides requires body syntax-body unexported max-let-depth dummy lang-info internal-context pre-submodules post-submodules)
  in: (struct mod (name srcname self-modidx prefix provides requires body syntax-body unexported max-let-depth dummy lang-info internal-context pre-submodules post-submodules))
  context...:
   /Applications/racket/collects/racket/match/parse-helper.rkt:68:0: parse-struct
   /Applications/racket/collects/racket/match/gen-match.rkt:68:29: mk
   /Applications/racket/collects/racket/match/gen-match.rkt:47:15: for-loop
   /Applications/racket/collects/racket/match/gen-match.rkt:23:0: go
   standard-module-name-resolver
   standard-module-name-resolver
   standard-module-name-resolver
   standard-module-name-resolver
   /Users/vhsmaia/Library/Racket/planet/300/5.3.5/cache/dyoo/whalesong.plt/1/19/whalesong.rkt: [running body]
```

Comment: This is probably my responsibility.  I need to prepare a version of Whalesong for 5.3.6 and get it deployed onto PLaneT.  I thought I had done this earlier, but I must be mistaken!  'll try to do so as soon as I can.

Comment: Just to follow up on this: A working version of Whalesong Racket version 6xx is available on Github.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd try is updating Racket to 5.3.6.